# mongoDB updateMany fields on Array

Tags: mongodb

[image]

i want to update all fields on adress , i tried $ operator and alot of other stuff that on docs , but it always fail . whats am i missing?

code :
[image]
params that function gets is
[image]

Comment: Looks like the address field is just plain values of attributes: `[data.country, data.city ...]` so in the `$set` operator you could just do `{ $set: {addres: [data.country, data.city, data.zip, data.street, data.nostreet, data.noaprtment, data.phonenumber ] } }` Note: this will overwrite the whole address field

Answer (score 0):

To update a position of an array you should use Dot notation.

In this case `address.0` `addrees.1` and so on

This is an example of the data that you provided:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/kSYLDs3jPkP

I used update but you should be able to use updateMany too

Comment: doesn't works :(

Comment: Send the code, it should work. Worked on the example that I sent

Comment: remember the quotes

Comment: it's just because I have address with two 'ss' replace that with your addres field

Comment: ah yes its works THANKS , there was a mistake on my 'addres' instead 'address;

Comment: Niceee! If that worked please accept or positively mark the answer:D